# Printing a Pattern with While loops and only using three output statements in C

Tags: c, printing, while-loop

I have an assignment for school that is really got the best of me.

Here is the question:

> (2) Write a C program using while
>   loop(s) in combination with only the
>   following three output statements
>   (Each one appearing ONLY ONCE in your
>   program): printf("* ");  printf("\n");
>   printf(“^“); to print  the pattern:
>
> ```
> * * * * * * * * ^
> * * * * * * * *
> * * * * * * * * ^
> * * * * * * * *
> * * * * * * * * ^
> * * * * * * * *
> ```
>
> Note: there is a space between each *
>   and the first, third, and fifth lines
>   have a space before the  ^.

And here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main () {

 int star = 0;
 int row = 1;
 int hat = 1;

 while(row < 6) {

  printf(" *");
  star++; 

  while(star > 8) {

   while( (hat % 2) == 1) {

    printf(" ^"); 
   }

   printf("\n");
   row++;
  }
 }
    return 0; 
}
```

I've tried many different versions of this code, and most of them ended up with infinitely printing rows of *.

If anyone could help it would be great as I've tried and tried at this for a while now and even though I wish I could keep trying deadlines are deadlines and they always seem to come too fast.

Thanks

**EDIT:**

Rev.2 of the code:

```
include<stdio.h>

int main () {
int star = 0;
int row = 1;
int hat = 0;

while(row <= 6) {

    printf(" *");
    star++; 

    while(star >= 8) {
        hat++;  

        if( (hat % 2) == 1) {
            printf(" ^");
            hat++;  
        }

        printf("\n");
        row++;
        star = 0;
    }
}
return 0;   
}
```

Hopefully I am terminating the loops correctly but It seems not to be working.
I'm not asking for a "get out of jail free" card but any are welcomed.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My answer is here

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
    int row = 0;
    int hat = 0;
    while(row < 6) {
            int col = 0;
            while(col < 8) {
              printf("* ");
              col++;
            }
            while( (hat % 2) == 0) {
              printf("^");
              hat++;
            }
            printf("\n");
            row++;
            hat = row;
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems like I was wanting to over nest everything, Thanks to everyone.

Comment: Is giving a complete solution without comment really a good thing for a homework question? @Craig, this may work, but do you understand what's wrong with your own non-working solutions?

Comment: @Secure, Do you really need comment for such self-describing code? 
Also by the time i was adding code , people had already provided comments with the problem.

Comment: For a learner at Craig's level, usually there is no such thing as "self-describing code".

Comment: As long as we're writing entire solutions, this one isn't even very good.  Why do you need a while loop for a statement that will only increment once?  Why do you need an extra counter to keep track of whether the row is even-numbered?  Why do you increment `hat` just to later assign it to the value of `row` (other than to get out of that ill-conceived loop)?

Comment: @danben, the requirement is to only use while loop.
of course the while ((hat %2) ==0) loop can more efficiently be implemented as an if statement but what's the fun if there are no constraints.

Comment: There is nothing in the program statement that says "only while loops".  The only constraint is on the output statements.

Answer (score 2):

The first problem is in this block:

```
 while(star > 8) {

   while( (hat % 2) == 1) {

    printf(" ^"); 
   }

   printf("\n");
   row++;
  }
```

You never reset `star` when going to the next row.

Also, I don't see you incrementing `hat` anywhere.

I'm surprised that your stars print infinitely - since `hat` starts at 1 and does not change inside that `while` loop, that loop should never terminate.

Another problem - `star` counts the number of stars you've printed already, right?  So you only want 8 stars per row, but waiting until `star > 8` will allow you to print 9 per row.

Answer (score 2):

Just a hint:

```
   while( (hat % 2) == 1) {
```

should be an `if()` and should be placed somewhere else in your program.

Answer (score 0):

`hat` is fixed, i.e. no incrementing anywhere and `star` is not being reset each time in the loop...I have highlighted the problematic lines...

```
while(row < 6) {

  printf(" *");
  star++; 

  while(star > 8) {

   while( (hat % 2) == 1) { // since hat = 1, 1%2 == 1 is true....

    printf(" ^"); 
   }

   printf("\n");
   row++;
  }

  star = 0; // !!!

 }
```

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.

Answer (score 0):

When you have an infinite while-loop, then check your loops for this pattern:

```
var = inital value;
while (var has not exitcondition)
{
    ....
    var = modify value;
}
```

The usual cause for an infinite loop is that the modification of var is not inside the loop, so var will never reach the exitcondition.